# Github checks + action integration

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to implement eslint check everytime I push code in GitHub  and I came across checks(https://developer.github.com/apps/quickstart-guides/creating-ci-tests-with-the-checks-api/) in GitHub, but get couldn’t get much on “how-to setup” though it has all the apis and other stuff to integrate eslint with checks.

FYI, I have built a bot to check the git events using probot.github.io and it works well. Now I want to integrate checks with it.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you don't want to use [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) and set up a pre-commit hook?

Comment: @ummahusla: I am using husky as well. I just wanted to add the check in github as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ESLint GitHub Actions published to the marketplace that will do linting and annotations of pull requests. Perhaps one of those will fit your use-case.

Check them out here:
https://github.com/marketplace?utf8=%E2%9C%93&type=actions&query=eslint

Comment: I did see them @peterevans but I wanted to build something from scratch so that I can customize it as per my project needs as well as I would know the process of integrating the new feature "checks" from github :). Thanks for sharing the link.